# If + try - catch in method not working properly

Tags: java, android, if-statement, methods, try-catch

I'm working on an SQLite based app. Everything is working fine, except my if-else statements in my method. The saving and stuff works, just the checking is giving me a pretty high blood pressure. I'm hoping one of you is much smarter than i am and finds the probably obvious mistake i made:

```
public void save() {

        // get length of EditText
        int dateLength, mileageLength, amountLength, lpriceLength, tpriceLength;

        dateLength = date_widget.getText().length();
        mileageLength = mileage_widget.getText().length();
        amountLength = amount_widget.getText().length();
        lpriceLength = price_widget.getText().length();
        tpriceLength = totalPrice_widget.getText().length();

        // Start save method if EditTexts are not empty.

        if (dateLength > 0 || mileageLength > 0 || amountLength > 0
                || lpriceLength > 0 || tpriceLength > 0) {

            // Get the value of each EditText and write it into the
            // String/doubles

            String date = date_widget.getText().toString();
            double mileage = Double
                    .valueOf(mileage_widget.getText().toString());
            double amount = Double.valueOf(amount_widget.getText().toString());
            double lprice = Double.valueOf(price_widget.getText().toString());
            double tprice = Double.valueOf(totalPrice_widget.getText()
                    .toString());

            // Check if mileage is increasing, else cancel and show toast
            int checkMileage = Integer.parseInt(db
                    .getSearchResult("mileage", 0));

            if (checkMileage < mileage) {

                try {
                    // if (id == null) {
                    db.insert(date, mileage, amount, lprice, tprice);

                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.action_input_saved,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Your current mileage must be more than the last saved mileage",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "finish your input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

My Method in the DbAdapter class:

```
public String getSearchResult(String sql, int cmd) {

    if (cmd == 0) {
        String countQuery = "SELECT " + sql + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME
                + " WHERE _id = (SELECT max(_id) FROM " + TABLE_NAME + ")";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String tmp = cursor.getString(0);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return tmp;
    } else if (cmd == 1) {
        int sum = 0;
        String countQuery = "SELECT " + sql + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        String idQuery = "SELECT _id FROM " + TABLE_NAME
                + " WHERE _id = (SELECT max(_id) FROM " + TABLE_NAME + ")";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        Cursor id = db.rawQuery(idQuery, null);
        // berechnung
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        id.moveToFirst();

        int maxId = Integer.parseInt(id.getString(0));
        for (int i = 0; i < maxId; i++) {

            int tmp = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
            sum = sum + tmp;
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        id.close();
        return String.valueOf(sum);
    } else if (cmd == 2 && sql == "mileage") {
        int sum = 0;
        String countQuery = "SELECT " + sql + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        String idQuery = "SELECT _id FROM " + TABLE_NAME
                + " WHERE _id = (SELECT max(_id) FROM " + TABLE_NAME + ")";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        Cursor id = db.rawQuery(idQuery, null);
        // berechnung
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        id.moveToFirst();

        int maxId = Integer.parseInt(id.getString(0));
        if (maxId > 1) {
            int array[] = new int[maxId];

            // Array füllen
            for (int i = 0; i < maxId; i++) {

                array[i] = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
                // sum = sum + tmp;
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            for (int k = 1; k < maxId; k++) {
                int tmp;
                tmp = array[k] - array[k - 1];
                sum = sum + tmp;
            }

            cursor.close();
            id.close();
            return String.valueOf(sum);
        } else {
            return "--";
        }

    }
    return "Wrong CMD";

}
```

I is pretty messy, i know

Comment: In What way aren't they working? Exceptions, or simply not checking?

Comment: The app is crashing if i try to save without an input.

Comment: More info is needed. For now I can surely say you should use `&&` instead of  `||` in your first `if` statement.

Comment: sure thing, what info do you need?
ah cr... you're right. this was the missing piece in my head. THANK YOU :)

Comment: My first Problem has been solved but now i encounter one more thing.
how can i prevent an OutOfBoundsException at the "checkMileage" if statement?

Comment: always annotate @ somebody (e.g. @BorisStrandjev) if you want him notified - I wouldn't have looked if you have not revoked your accept. This second problem you have is a matter for second question I would say. There also post the code of `db.getSearchResult` because I think your problem lies there somewhere.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev ah okay, didnt know that. I will post the method in my first post above.
Strange thing is: even if i get rid of the checkMileage thing there is nothing being processed on my mein thread. There is nothing arriving there or something i dont get it.

Comment: @mike.b93 what exactly error are you getting? Now with the code in front of me I can tell it is not in the `getSearchResult`

Comment: @BorisStrandjev If the Database is empty i get an CurserOutOfBoundsException when trying to fill the DB with a first entry.

The big thing is, that my textViews on my MainActivity arn't always populated. that's another thing that makes me itchy

Comment: `String tmp = cursor.moveToFirst() ? cursor.getString(0) : "default_val";` instead of most of the code you have for case 0.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev Ah didn't know i can do it like that. This works, and somehow, my TextViews on my MainActivity are being calculated right again.
May i ask what the "?" does exactly? is this some kind of an "AND" operator? Anywhere i can read about this?

Thank you so mich for your time :) you're the King :)

Comment: This is called ternary operator and is basically equivalent to `if`/`else` construction (I used it because in comments it is inconvenient to write multiple lines). Read about it here: http://java.about.com/b/2009/06/06/java-term-of-the-week-ternary-operator.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning comment into an answer:

Switch all `||` to `&&` in your first `if`. Otherwise you will try to process everything even if only one field is filled in.